# Identifying strange readings from Arduino EMF detector

Tags: arduino, sensor, antenna, emf

## Intro and knowledge self assessment

Full disclosure, I'm an amateur, and my knowledge of electronics is cursory, and I'm more into computer science. But I bought an knock off arduino kit, and decide to try some some projects. Things mostly worked out, and I verified that the board, despite somewhat non-official provenience, works as it should.

## The issue itself: EMF detector readings

I encountered some difficulty when attempting to construct an EMF detector. After reading number of tutorials I went ahead and implemented the sensor setup from [DIY Ultra Sensitive EMF Detector](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/mircemk/diy-ultra-sensitive-emf-detector-4be895) , with the rest trimmed to the very bone. So no LCD, buzzer, or LED. All information instead being relayed directly trough serial and plotted.

My reasoning was that as I am a novice, and this is my first project concerning detection of anything beyond visible spectrum, I might want to keep things as simple as possible.
Plus, I was more interested in the signal than beeps.

So I ended up with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccc0k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the antenna I used telescopic from an old radio and 3M resistor. I have set the main loop to obtain and send raw readings every 0.3 sec.

To my surprise I saw a very clear periodicity in the readings, with peak about every 26 seconds and minimum close to zero.

The device was sitting on my table. And the closest source of the signal I could think of, were, in order of distance, small speaker, and PC. The period persisted, even after I turned the speaker off. And I'm not sure how could PC produce the signal I saw.

There are no powerlines over, or under the house, that I know off, the area is residential.

I've repeated the experiment with different antenna, this time it was hand (well technically  I used a hand drill) wound coil of solid core copper wire. The signal remained the same, and it remained even after I adjusted the delay for reading to 1 sec.

The signal appears to be stronger in specific directions, so I'm not completely discounting the option that there is a real source. Other odd thing is that the detector doesn't seem to pick up anything near power outlets, extension cords or powered devices. So it doesn't seem to work at all, apart from picking up that weird signal.

Nevertheless I have no idea what could be, leaving the option that I, somehow, made a slowly discharging capacitor of sorts. But I don't see how that would happen.

### Question itself

So what could it be? Did I make some sort of obvious mistake? What kind of source could produce the signal I'm seeing?

The raw readings from serial (just one period it would be too long otherwise):

> 100
> 47
> 51
> 43
> 27
> 10
> 3
> 2
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 9
> 17
> 29
> 35
> 48
> 61
> 80
> 83
> 85
> 82
> 81
> 74
> 66
> 64
> 65
> 72
> 77
> 83
> 93
> 99
> 83
> 79
> 78
> 73
> 69

Comment: Where is the nearest cellphone?

Comment: @JackCreasey 20-180cm away, depending on the position. I've moved the antenna a bit to get readings from wider area. But the signal seemed to be stronger further away.

Comment: The 26-second period you're seeing *could* be an alias. Most fields that your antenna probe picks up would likely have 50 Hz or 60 Hz frequency (a period of 16.6 ms or 20 ms).  Arduino's *sample rate* may be near some multiple of this frequency.

Comment: Change your sample rate VERY slightly and note the periodicity now. 0.3s is either 15 or 18 complete cycles of nominal mains frequency, while 26 seconds contains either 1300 or 1560 cycles of mains. So a frequency error of 1/1300 in either your sample rate or mains frequency will give this sort of aliasing. Now a similar change in sample rate (to 0.3002 seconds or 0.2998) will either halve the period or enormously extend it... If that happpens, you are seeing mains power electric fields, and sampling them much faster (> 200Hz, < 5 ms) will let you see much more accurately.

Comment: @user_1818839 You seem to have hit the nail on the head! With the readings set to every 0.2998 secs the the period  is cut in half. And when I set the sampling rate to 5 ms I can see smooth changes in peaks as I approach the power outlet. Could you please turn your comment into an answer? So I can give it upvote and mark it as a resolution?